# Products and Bill of Materials

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a products table link to a bill of materials table. See diagram[image: ER Diagram]

Each product can have more than one formula. For example:

[image: Sample Data]

Currently ProdIDNeed and ProdIDNeeded are my composite primary key, both fields also link as foreign keys to ProdID (Products). The only way I can think of preventing a key violation is to create a Formula field and have a 3 field composite primary key (ProdIDNeed, ProdIDNeeded, FormulaNumber).

However, I have to link the product_billmaterials table to a workorders table (bascially an order to make the product according to formula). Linking three fields to another table is a pain.

I guess I could also create a surrogate key on the product_billmaterials table which I am not too crazy about either.

Is there any other way I can organize this or must I choose one of the options I have thought of?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The formula number refers to the formula for each product. One product can have several formulas. A product may have one or several possible formulas that make the same product. The FK puts a constraint on the ProdID.

Comment: Some products are a mixture of other chemicals, some are not. Let us say that ProdID 1000 is a mixture of prodID 1001, prodID 1002 and prodID 1003. ProdID 1000 can also be a mixture of prodID 1001, prodID 1003, and prodID 1005. Here we see two formulas for ProdID 1000. Therefore prodID 1000 =prodIDneed,  and its components are prodIDneeded. Basically it refers to the product(need) and components(needed). Each product and its components must be listed in the products table thus the FK constraints.